# Underlining Text in an <input> Box

Tags: html, double, textfield, underline

I've gotten a request from a client to underline text in a text field.
Both single and double lines.

Is this even possible? I assume with some obscure plugin but I haven't found it yet. :P

I've thought about there being 2 possibilities, if this is possible.

1. Underlining the text in the actual field.
2. Doing some crazy hack with text just underneath the text field.

Thanks for any help and/or commentary. ^_^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following works in Chrome 6.0.472.55/Ubuntu 10.04, and Firefox 3.6.9 (also Ubuntu 10.04):

```
input {text-decoration: underline; }
```

Though this, obviously, gives only a single-underline.

Quick demo at: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/asuwo3)

Comment: *find something that accomplishes a double underline.

Comment: @bobber205: I wish you well in that search, I suspect that it will likely involve javascript chicanery and dark arts beyond my ken. ...at this time of night, anyway... *yawn* =b

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a CSS based solution i.e. a CSS selector to underline the text.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic example of how to accomplish this.

Still can't do it out of the box, but fairly simple to do with a little Sass and JS

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/davidwieler/pen/XWrQqRG)

```html
<h1>Underline search input</h1>
<form class="search">
    <label class="inputs">
        <span class="label-tag">Search</span>
        <input placeholder="Search" type="text" value="">
        <span class="search-highlight"></span>
        <span class="search-highlight-second"></span>
    </label>
    <button type="submit"> Search </button>
</form>
```

```
form {
    label {
        position: relative;

        .label-tag {
            display: none;
        }

        .search-highlight, .search-highlight-second {
            user-select: none;
            border-top: 1px solid #75d46b;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            bottom: -2px;
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 0;
            color: transparent;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .search-highlight-second {
            bottom: -4px;
        }

        input {
            border: none;

            &:focus {
                outline: none;
            }
        }
    }


    button {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
}
```

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const highlightEl = document.getElementsByClassName('search-highlight')
const highlightElTwo = document.getElementsByClassName('search-highlight-second')

input.oninput = handleInput;

function handleInput(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    highlightEl[0].innerHTML = e.target.value
    highlightElTwo[0].innerHTML = e.target.value
}
```