# HTML character code to underline next character

Tags: html, underline

Like:

```
abcdef 
 _
```

What HTML character code I need to insert before `b` to make b underlined?

I need this inside a html attribute (value of a input field), so html tags like `<u>` are not acceptable

---

example:

`<input type="submit" value="UnderlineMeifUknowHow" accesskey="n" />`

I want the first "n" from UnderlineMeifUknowHow to be underlined

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681436/underlining-text-in-an-input-box

Comment: Wait you're trying to underline a character within an `<input>` tag?  I don't believe that's possible, short of using some rich text editor control.

Comment: yes, or underline certain text inside a tag attribute

Comment: I know it's possible I've seen it somewhere, not html, but it was some kind of code :)

Comment: But if "some kind of code" wasn't in a browser, it's not relevant.

Comment: Well, Facebook lets you refer to usernames in their comment box and will highlight them using a grey background.  They do this by making the `textarea` transparent, and then positioning a div with the rich content behind the `textbox`.  I suppose you could do something like that if you were dead set on getting this effect.

Comment: In fact, it is possible with some (gosh im looking for 20 min now) special characters. A few people used these in 2005 in Counter-Strike: Source (seriously) to modify their names. I this is what @Alex is looking for: http://cl.ly/270p1Y1u0D44160f3a1P

Comment: I think some programs support ANSI escape sequences, such as `\fu` to start underlining and `\fn` to stop.  Console apps would support this on most OS's, and I think some IRC programs will parse these.  HTML text box?  I think not (I tried it just for fun, and no)..

Comment: see how you can use a function to do it for you @Alex - at my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I tould you in the question-comments, there are special characters and I finally found it!

e̲

Poorly it depends on the font you're using to move the underline directly under the letter. It's also known as a "combining character" and can be found under U+0332 in the unicode table.

Comment: thank you it does what I asked, but it looks ugly, the underlined character gets smaller :x

Comment: There's also a longer version of this, which is U+035F: e ͟

Comment: Please don't tell us, you just wanted to underline a letter on a button... Because there's already something for this in html called `accessKey` for the `<button>`

Comment: lol this works: `<button accesskey="o">C<u>o</u>olButton</button>`

Comment: @Alex; Well, yes. That's not an attribute, you can put any flow content in a `<button>`. (And with unicode support being what it is on some platforms and with some fonts, I wouldn't rely on this solution. Interesting nonetheless.)

Answer (score 7):

You can simply put `&#818;` after any word and it becomes underlined, its a HTML Code.

```
<input type=button value=S&#818;end>
```

It becomes:

S̲end

But you can create a JavaScript function to do it for you, see:

```
function underlineWord(pos,str){
  str = str.substring(0,pos) + str[pos] + "&#818;" + str.substring(pos+1,str.length);
  return str;
}
```

This way, if you execute:

```
underlineWord(0,"string");
```

You will have:

s̲tring

Comment: Worked in IE, not Chrome.  Chrome gave a square block in front of the character.  It may also be dependent on the font used.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
abcde<br />
<span style="visibility:hidden">a</span>_
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fXMrN/

Comment: I thought that, but I believed it was my geeky nature :)

Comment: the result of quick thoughts, promise I won't do it again :P

Answer (score 3):

Try `a<u>b</u>cdef`, this should help. Read more about HTML [tag u](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_u.asp).

Answer (score 3):

you could wrap b with a `<span>` styled with `text-decoration:underline` or a `<u>`

Answer (score 2):

Use `<u>` tags

Please note that the `<u>` tags is deprecated and thus will invalidate your document. It's been deprecated because users can confuse it with a link and makes for confusions

In any case you should be using CSS for any styling

Comment: No, the `<u>` *element* has been deprecated because it is presentational markup. The favored method to apply presentation is CSS.

Comment: _The <u> element is redefined in HTML5, to represent text that should be stylistically different from normal text, such as misspelled words or proper nouns in Chinese._ [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_u.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean surround b with the u tag?

```
<u>b</u>
```

To be standards compliant, I would use inline CSS:

```
<span style="text-decoration:underline;">b</span>
```

I would refer to a guide such as http://w3schools.com/html/ to get answers to quick reference questions like this.

Comment: Ok, well there are many other guides out there too such as http://zvon.org/comp/m/html.html or guides by O'Reilly.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
<style>
  .underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
</style>
```

Markup:

```
<input style="text-decoration:underline;" type="submit" value="underlined" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do inside an attribute like you want to, and FWIW you probably shouldn't style text inside attributes anyway.

Outside attributes (i.e. using HTML elements), one could use the `<u>` element, but that is presentational markup and generally considered a bad idea. The best way to underline something is to use CSS (`text-decoration: underline;`) on whatever element you want underlined.